# IntelliJ Github Login Token With Options?

Tags: github, intellij-idea, authentication, token

When making a GitHub token for my IntelliJ login, it has options to choose like read and write repos, create gist, and more and I don't know what to choose for it to work with IntelliJ.. Any help, i'm trying to login with token on IntelliJ so i can create a gist of something i'm working on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, for all GitHub operations to work fine from IntelliJ, you need **repo** (all subcategories if you want to work with private repos) and **gists** scopes.

IntelliJ could create a token itself if you add an account in settings and provide your login/password and 2FA code (optional) when prompted.